# Returning the last element of a list in haskell using recursion

Tags: haskell

How do I get the last element in a list in haskell? I have written some of the code below:

```
lastList :: List a -> a
lastList lst =
   case lst of
       Cons x xs -> lastList xs
       Cons _ xs -> lastList xs
       Empty    -> error "lastList of empty list"
```

How do I do it without using any of the built in functions?

Comment: You don't. You get a Maybe last element!

Comment: Are you worried about using the built-in function 'error' ?

Answer (score 7):

You just have to check when an element is cons with an `Empty`:

```
lastList :: List a -> a
lastList lst =
   case lst of
       Cons x Empty -> x
       Cons _ xs    -> lastList xs
       Empty        -> error "lastList of empty list"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Cons` is a *Lisp* like list where a list is represented as a linked list. Each `Cons h t` is a node where `h` refers to the *head* of that node (an element), an the `t` to the *tail* of the list: the remainder. Furthermore the end of the list (the empty list) is here represented with `Empty`.

So that means that a *list with one element* `x` is represented as `Cons x Empty` (this is equivalent to `[x]`). In case we encounter this, we have to return `x`, since the last element of a list with one element is that element.

So the question is what to do in the case we have a `Cons h t` where `t` is not `Empty`. In that case the list thus looks like `[x1,x2,...]`. Now the last element of that list is the same as the last element of the `[x2,x3,...]` list, so we can use recursion on the tail.

Finally we have to find a way to resolve the case where we provide an empty list to the function. In that case we probably better provide an `error`.

So we can implement it like:

```
lastList :: List a -> a
lastList (Cons h Empty) = h
lastList (Cons _ t) = lastList t
lastList Empty = error "An empty list has no lastElement"
```